# Missing Return Statement?

Tags: bluej

This is my code. when I compile using bluej it highlights the last } and says missing return statement. I cant put void because it is a boolean. ANy ideas?

```
 public boolean runAJob() {
     boolean jobsFinished = false;
     Job firstJob = getCurrentJob();
     String jobName = firstJob.getName();
     int jobDuration = firstJob.getDuration();
     if (!myJob.isEmpty()&& jobDuration > 0 && jobDuration <= myTotalDuration) { 
         myTotalDuration -= jobDuration;
         myFinishedJobs.add(myJob.get(0));
         myJob.remove(0);
         System.out.println("'"+jobName+"'" +" is completed. "+ myTotalDuration+ " seconds remaining on the clock");
         jobsFinished = true;
    } else {
          System.out.println("JobQueue is empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem in putting return jobsFinished;

Answer (score 1):

In Java, as in C-like languages, require a return statement based on the return type of the method / function.

In your case:

```
public boolean runAJob() { ... }
```

Requires that a **boolean** be returned. **As such, when you try to compile the code, and there isn't a return statement in your method body, the compiler will complain.**

So, what you have to do is determine what information you wish to return(a boolean in this case). As others have pointed out, you should return **jobsFinished since that is a boolean type whose value you wish to determine upon the method call**.

```
 public boolean runAJob()
    {
        boolean jobsFinished = false;
        Job firstJob = getCurrentJob();
        String jobName = firstJob.getName();
        int jobDuration = firstJob.getDuration();
        if (!myJob.isEmpty()&& jobDuration > 0 && jobDuration <= myTotalDuration)
        { 
             myTotalDuration -= jobDuration;
             myFinishedJobs.add(myJob.get(0));
             myJob.remove(0);
             System.out.println("'"+jobName+"'" +" is completed. "+ myTotalDuration+ " seconds remaining on the clock");
             jobsFinished = true;
             return jobsFinished; //this is one possible place

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("JobQueue is empty");
        }
        //here is another possible place where you could have put the return
        //return jobsFinished;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply return jobsFinished.

To be clear:

```
public boolean runAJob()
        {
            boolean jobsFinished = false;
            Job firstJob = getCurrentJob();
            String jobName = firstJob.getName();
            int jobDuration = firstJob.getDuration();
            if (!myJob.isEmpty()&& jobDuration > 0 && jobDuration <= myTotalDuration)
            { 
                 myTotalDuration -= jobDuration;
                 myFinishedJobs.add(myJob.get(0));
                 myJob.remove(0);
                 System.out.println("'"+jobName+"'" +" is completed. "+ myTotalDuration+ " seconds remaining on the clock");
                 jobsFinished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("JobQueue is empty");
            }
            return jobsFinished;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**return Statement must be always the last statement in the method**

```
public boolean runAJob()
    {
        boolean jobsFinished = false;

        Job firstJob = getCurrentJob();

        String jobName = firstJob.getName();

        int jobDuration = firstJob.getDuration();

        if (!myJob.isEmpty()&& jobDuration > 0 && jobDuration <= myTotalDuration)

        { 

             myTotalDuration -= jobDuration;

             myFinishedJobs.add(myJob.get(0));

             myJob.remove(0);

             System.out.println("'"+jobName+"'" +" is completed. "+ myTotalDuration+ "
```

seconds remaining on the clock");

```
             jobsFinished = true;

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("JobQueue is empty");

        }

        return jobsFinished;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to put
    return jobsFinished;
after the end of the System.out.print line.
When you do, it should run and compile successfully, which I am sure of because I made the same mistake today :P

Good luck.

-Keelen

Answer (score 0):

Change your function definition/prototype... Use this `public void runAJob()` instead of what you have used...

Replace `boolean` with `void` in the prototype.. And then try

Answer (score 0):

You have specified a `boolean` return type but your function doesn't return any value.

The `jobsFinished` variable is redundant, as is your `else` branch:

```
public boolean runAJob() {
    Job firstJob = getCurrentJob();    
    int jobDuration = firstJob.getDuration();

    if (!myJob.isEmpty() && jobDuration > 0 && jobDuration <= myTotalDuration) { 
        String jobName = firstJob.getName();
        myTotalDuration -= jobDuration;
        myFinishedJobs.add(myJob.get(0));
        myJob.remove(0);
        System.out.println("'"+jobName+"'" +" is completed. "+ myTotalDuration+ " seconds remaining on the clock");
        return true;
    } 

    System.out.println("JobQueue is empty");
    return false;
}
```

If the conditions are satisfied, the function will `return` before the last two statements anyway, so an `else` isn't necessary. I also moved the `String jobName = firstJob.getName();` inside the `if` branch because you're not using it otherwise.

If you prefer to use a `boolean` variable, and `return` it at the end of the function, then you could do:

```
public boolean runAJob() {
    Job firstJob = getCurrentJob();    
    int jobDuration = firstJob.getDuration();
    boolean jobsFinished = !myJob.isEmpty() && jobDuration > 0 && jobDuration <= myTotalDuration;
    if (jobsFinished) { 
        String jobName = firstJob.getName();
        myTotalDuration -= jobDuration;
        myFinishedJobs.add(myJob.get(0));
        myJob.remove(0);
        System.out.println("'"+jobName+"'" +" is completed. "+ myTotalDuration+ " seconds remaining on the clock");            
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("JobQueue is empty");
    }   
    return jobsFinished;
}
```